# String Index out of range when using Hazelcast readUTF

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast, serializable, hazelcast-imap

I am using DataSerializable in Hazelcast to serialize a custom class which I am then storing in a cache to be accessed by a web-app running in a tomcat server. Earlier I was getting a NPE as the custom classes contained some fields which could be null as well. I fixed that by adding a check such that if that particular field is null. It does a `writeUTF("null")` but now when I am reading a list of String fields in this manner

```
    int foldersCount = in.readInt();
    for (int k = 0; k< foldersCount; k++){

        String f = in.readUTF();
        this.folders.add(f);
    }
```

The writeData looks like this-

```
if (this.folders == null){
        out.writeUTF("null");
    }

    else{

        out.writeInt(this.folders.size());
        for (String b: this.folders){
            out.writeUTF(b);
        }

    }
```

I get the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -67043329
at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readUTF(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:569)
at o.c.i.y.s.d.s.readData(User.java:433)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:191)
at com.hazelcast.internal.nearcache.impl.store.AbstractNearCacheRecordStore.dataToValue(AbstractNearCacheRecordStore.java:186)
at com.hazelcast.internal.nearcache.impl.store.AbstractNearCacheRecordStore.toValue(AbstractNearCacheRecordStore.java:206)
at com.hazelcast.internal.nearcache.impl.store.BaseHeapNearCacheRecordStore.updateAndGetReserved(BaseHeapNearCacheRecordStore.java:164)
at com.hazelcast.internal.nearcache.impl.store.AbstractNearCacheRecordStore.tryPublishReserved(AbstractNearCacheRecordStore.java:413)
at com.hazelcast.internal.nearcache.impl.DefaultNearCache.tryPublishReserved(DefaultNearCache.java:217)
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.NearCachedClientMapProxy.tryPublishReserved(NearCachedClientMapProxy.java:575)
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.NearCachedClientMapProxy.getInternal(NearCachedClientMapProxy.java:128)
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:297)
at o.c.i.y.s.d.persistence.UserDAO.getContextInfo(UserDAO.java:1058)
at o.c.i.y.s.d.s.persistence.UserDAO.getUserInfo(UserDAO.java:890)
at o.c.i.y.s.d.s.service.impl.UserRestServiceImpl.getLoginUserInfo(UserRestServiceImpl.java:250)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT**

New Read/Write Method

Write Method

```
if (this.folders == null) {
        out.writeInt(-1);
    }
    else{
        int foldersCount = this.folders.size();
        out.writeInt(foldersCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < foldersCount; ++i) {
            String b = this.folders.get(i);
            out.writeUTF(b);
        }
    }
```

Read Method

```
int foldersCount = in.readInt();
    if (foldersCount == -1)
        this.folders = null;
    else{
        for (int k = 0; k< foldersCount; k++){

            String f = in.readUTF();
            this.folders.add(f);
        }
    }
```

Still gives same error

Comment: This indicates that your `readData` / `writeData` implementations are not symmetric. Can you post both methods? Also, you may find useful the `read/writeUTFArray` methods available in `ObjectDataInput/Output`.

Comment: ive posted both the write and read method

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
    out.writeUTF("null");
```

more general would be

```
    out.writeInt(0);
```

The reason being that a `null` should be equivalent to an empty collection.

It is crucial that on writing, the content of `folders` should not be changed, so the written size
corresponds with the number of UTF strings written.

Maybe indeed do:

```
    if (this.folders == null) {
        this.folders = Collections.emptyList();
    }
    int foldersCount = this.folders.size();
    out.writeInt(foldersCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < foldersCount; ++i) {
        String b = this.folders.get(i);
        out.writeUTF(b);
    }
```

The case of null being removed.

Comment: Okay, then something is fishy: BTW the illegal index is in hex: FC00FFFF. Will add to the answer

Comment: still the same the code that gets highlighted in eclipse is `String f = in.readUTF()` maybe the solution is to make read and write method symmetrical as @vassilis says. The only reason I am doing a null check is becaue writeUTF throws a NPE if folders turns out to be a null value

Comment: So maybe `folders.get(i)` might be null for some i? You are right, the code must be symmetrical. `this.folders` means there is no recursion at that spot. Nevertheless you may solve it better at your side.

Comment: Folders itself might be null which throws the exception

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `readData` method always expects an `int` as the first field to read, however if on the serializing side `folders` was `null`, then the byte stream contains actually a `String` resulting in a mismatch of serialized types vs what is being deserialized on the receiving end, hence the serialization exception.

To avoid this situation, you can encode the `null` value as a different `int` eg use -1 to indicate `null` like in the following example. This way, you are certain there is always an `int` at the first 4 bytes and depending on its value you can decide whether it indicates a `null` or proceed further with reading `folders` elements.

```
void readData(ObjectDataInput in) {
  int length = in.readInt();
  if (length == -1) {
    folders = null;
  } else {
    folders = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      folders.add(in.readUTF());
    }
  }
}

void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) {
  if (folders == null) {
    out.writeInt(-1);
    return;
  }
  out.writeInt(folders.size());
  for (String s : folders) {
    out.writeUTF(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -67043329` still gives the same error